# Prove that the following limit is 0

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I have to prove this following statement.

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ a sequence of independent random variables with $\mathbf E(X_i) = 0$ and $\mathbf{Var}(X_i)=C<\infty$ for all $ i \in \Bbb >N $. Let $ p >1/2 $ and $S_n=X_1+...+X_n $.
>
> Show that $ \lim_{n\to \infty}S_n/n^p =0$ in probability.

I think that I should use the central limit theorem, but I am not sure because this way does not lead me to something..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it given that the distributions of the variables are the same?

Comment: @NCh No, I do not think so.

Comment: Hint: Show the convergence in $L^2$.

Comment: @DavideDima Then you cannot use central limit theorem without additional conditions.